# How to mirror Windows 7 to Samsung Smart TV (32J4300-joy smart)?

Tags: windows-7

I have a Samsung Smart TV (Model: 32J4300 Joy Smart). It has built-in Wifi adapter. As mentioned in the description of TV, it support screen mirroring through compatible android devices like my Xiaomi phone. So it flawlessly mirrors my phone screen. But my query is 
"Is is possible to mirror laptop screen wirelessly over the network on the Smart TV? If so then how? specify any additional software".

Currently I have Windows 7 Ultimate installed on my laptop.

I have already tried:
AirParrot
AirServer (incompatible with my windows 7 ultimate version)
Intel WiDi (incompatible with my laptop's processor or chipset)
Samsung AllShare (Does not detect any TV device, not even on the same network)
Samsung SmartView 2.0

Please provide detailed description and download link for any additional software. (And please study about given TV model specifically)
Thanks You

Comment: You have eliminated all your choices.  At least by a wireless solution

Comment: so what should I do?

Comment: You should be able to mirror your display using a HDMI cable.

Comment: That I know, I am asking for any wireless solution.

Comment: See my first comment.  You eliminated the wireless solutions.

Comment: If you could somehow get an android device to mirror your laptop's screen by a short cable, and then make the TV mirror the android wirelessly, you would have a setup that allows you to move around the room easily. (I'm assuming that is why you want it to be wireless.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that in some cases, installing an Intel network adapter driver will actually break MiraCast functionality. whereas installing a compatible Realtek driver may retain it.  This occurred on a Windows 10 build I owned a few years back.

Answer (score 2):

Your laptop would have to be Miracast or WiDi certified. If it's not you can't do much about it as software can't bridge the lack of hardware.

For example no matter what driver or software you install, there is no way in Hell you can print to paper without the printer itself.

-EDIT-

According to HP, 4440s supports WiDi (Intel computers will support WiDi, not miracast). Go to [HP support page](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=5229487&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=4059) for your computer and in multimedia driver section download and install "Intel Wireless Display Software". After you install it it should scan arround and offer you any wireless capable display to project to.

Some systems will simply detect the display as it was plugged in via cable - Windows 8 and Windows 10 will see it available if you simply press Windows Key + P, not sure about 7, don't have any left.

Comment: Is there any way to know, whether my laptop is MiraCast certified or not?

Comment: I have HP Probook 4440s (intel i5).

Comment: It does support WiDi, see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Win 7 like mine does not have the built in feature to detect Smart TV for screen mirroring (too bad) unless you have Win 10. But there is a go around way. Usually, most of the latest smart phone will have screen mirror feature to output to Smart TV wirelessly. Next, you just need to install free Teamviewer (for personal use only) on both of your Smart phone and Win 7 and let the Smart phone take control on Win 7 screen remotely. So, in this way, Smart TV can receive Win 7 screen thru your Smart phone. Pretty Smart right?